# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT docker api

Tags: docker, api

I have to dockerize an API with Flask. My API has an endpoint /images which returns the result of a predefined function in JSON format, with parameters q and links. The code that runs the API has the port defined with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 4000)
```

In shell. I build the docker image with:
`docker build -t test .`

In shell. I run the the docker image with:
`docker run -p 8080:4000 test`

An I obtain something like:
`Running on http://172.17.0.2:4000/`

When I request `http://172.17.0.2:4000/images?q=query&links=number`, the site can't be reached and ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZcwR.png)

Comment: You should test it on http://localhost:4000/ . Because IP 172.x.x.x is private IP of docker.

Comment: Thanks. It returns: This site can’t be reached.

Comment: Could you run `docker ps -a`. And share the output